# jquery autocomplete - Conditional styling of dropdown result

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Depending on a specific value of a records' status ("ACTIVE" vs. "INACTIVE") I want to give each record of the dropdown result a certain background-color. How to do so? I tried the below:

json:

```
[{"id":"1234","label":"Player","status":"ACTIVE"},{"id":"1235","label":"Player","status":"ACTIVE"}, ...]
```

js:

```
...
autocomplete: ({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        ...
      },                        
      create: function() {

            $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem  = function (ul, item) {
                return $( "<li>" )

                    if ( item.status == 'ACTIVE' ) { 
                        .append( "<a style='background-color: #eaffd6' href='/"+ item.id +"' >" + item.label + "</a>" )
                    }                   
                    if ( item.status == 'INACTIVE' ) {  
                        .append( "<a style='background-color: #ffe5e5' href='/"+ item.id +"' >" + item.label + "</a>" )
                    }   
                    //.append( "<a style='background-color: #ffe5e5' href='/"+ item.id +"' >" + item.label + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };

            $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderMenu = function( ul, items ) {
                var that = this;
                $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                    that._renderItemData( ul, item );
                });
            };          

        }       
    })
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your function `return`s before it even reaches your `if( item.status...)` so this code is never evaluated. Consider building the markup as a string and then returning the string of html when you've finished.
- I would add a class of `active` or `inactive` to the `<li>` element and then css rules `.active { background-color: #eaffd6; } .inactive { background-color: #ffe5e5 }`

**Edit** you could try something like

```
 $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem  = function (ul, item) {
    var str_html = '<li class="' + item.status.toLowerCase() + '">'
        + '<a href="/"' + item.id + '" >' + item.label + '</a>'
        + '</li>'
    return str_html''
};
```

Comment: Makes sense. I will add the classes ... but can you be more specific about the first point 'Consider building the markup as a string and then returning the string of html when you've finished.' and provide an example how to do so?

Comment: glad to help :)